# Set global react navigation navigationOptions based on props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I set my global navigationOptions based on props. My colors are stored in a theme object that’s available through context and allows switching between light and dark themes.

Id like to do something like this:

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: (props) => {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: props.theme.background,
      },
    },
  }
);
```

And then maybe adding the theme like

```
import myTheme from './theme'

const App = () => <RootStack theme={myTheme} />
```